# Get file extension in C

Tags: c, function

Is there a C library function to get the extension of file? I know that I can design a function on my own to get extension after '.' but not all files are stored with their extensions when we read them.

Comment: are you looking for the extension or the type of your file ?

Comment: if file is not stored with extension then how can you get it?

Comment: How do you expect to get the extension if it's not stored with the filename?  Are you trying to determine file formats such as PNG etc?  If that's what you want to do and can't rely on extension, you'll have to read the file headers.

Comment: Ah Sorry, i mean the type of the file like whether its a pdf, doc, odt , mp3, jpeg etc

Comment: @paddy: Is there any other way? No C library function?

Comment: C library doesn't cover platform/application specific stuff like this.

Comment: Man! this makes my task really difficult.

Comment: Sometimes when that's the case, you need to take a step back and ask yourself how important that really difficult task is.

Comment: Thanks @paddy i will do it, however difficult it may seem.

Comment: @ParthShah I generally reach the opposite conclusion and then get a brainwave.

Comment: I am waiting for my brainwave. I am going to need one!

Answer (score 4):

So you'd like to get the type of a file? Maybe the command 'file' in Linux is what you want. You can check its source code.

Comment: Yes I think this will help. How can I do that? Can you guide me?

Answer (score 3):

The `file` command in Linux uses a library called libmagic (don't confuse with libmagick) to check the 'magic' bytes in the file itself to determine the likely content type.

The library is fairly cross platform, it's well documented, for example here:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic